# Scrollify - on page refresh remains the same section

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

Am using **scrollify.js** latest version for page scroll effect and `updateHash` and `sectionName` are set to `false`.

Here my issue is, post page refresh focus is on the same section where I left. For example let say am in 4th section, when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> page has refreshed and landed on the same 4th section instead of landing in 1st section. Even <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> not helping in Chrome browser. Here is my code.

```js
$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
$.scrollify({
  section: ".scroll-section",
  sectionName: false,
  interstitialSection: "",
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  scrollSpeed: 1100,
  offset: 0,
  scrollbars: true,
  standardScrollElements: "",
  setHeights: true,
  overflowScroll: true,
  updateHash: false,
  touchScroll: true,
  before: function(index, section) {
    var className = '.' + $.scrollify.current().data('section');
    $('.sticky-left-nav').find('li').removeClass('active mb30');
    $('.sticky-left-nav').find(className).addClass('active mb30');

    if (index > 3) {
      $('body').removeAttr('style');
    } else {
      $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }
  },
  after: function() {},
  afterResize: function() {},
  afterRender: function() {}
});
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the native behaviour of all browsers. The browser will always return you to your last position on reload. Creating a hack to change this behaviour would be unwise.

Comment: @LukeHaas got your point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to the plugin. When the page `offsetTop` set, then after reload the browser scroll to the last position. You can see it a live [here](http://output.jsbin.com/bawiyom)

You can solve this by scroll the page back to top when page is loaded.

```js
$(window).on('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
  });
});
```

Live demo [here](http://output.jsbin.com/bovediz).

I'm not sure why we need `setTimeout` but that's the only way it works.

Comment: setting scrollTop(0) solves one issue and opens another. Now refresh lands on 1st section. But post that scroll-down not working, when i scroll-up it scrolls to 3rd section!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by combining a location change onload as well as scrolling to the top of the window.

```
    $(window).on('load', function() {
  location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/#1';
  setTimeout(function() {
      $(window).scrollTop(0);
      $.scrollify.update();
  });
});
```

You will have to adjust the location.href to your means as well as set updateHash to true so that the browser is aware of which hash you want it to go to onload